# filter array by removing elements with keys of type integer

Tags: php, arrays

If I have:

```
$my_array = array(0 => '172.16.6.50', "subnet" => "172.16.6.50");
```

What's the best way to delete all keys with integer type in `$my_array`?

Comment: **Hint**: use `foreach` and `is_int()`

Comment: If the array comes from a database, consider using associative fetch instead of manipulating the array after fetching.

Comment: @Maerlyn, my array comes from preg_match() function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick. :)

```
foreach($my_array as $key => $arr) {
    if(is_int($key)) {
        unset($my_array[$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you meaning to test `is_int` on the key rather?

Comment: Ohh ... yeah. Sorry, gonna fix it.

Comment: Take another look at the code - you have an additional error...

Comment: Yesyes, screw that bracket, cmon, dont be so harsh. :D

Comment: Well.. if people are gonna copy your answer you wanna make sure it's accurate :P

Comment: True that. Thanks for your persistence. :D

Comment: @Lix it can be also a strategy to find whether others copy your code :)

Comment: @YUNOWORK you can now test and remove that untested heading in your answer